# set scala breakpoints when creating library and testing using sbt

Tags: java, scala, debugging, intellij-idea

I have a library I'm creating using Intellij. I am doing TDD with ScalaTest and SBT to run my testing library. I want to set a breakpoint in Intellij for when it runs my tests to stop at a particular line so I can do inspection. How do I setup the run configuration to do this? When I extend my library class to `extend App` to give it a main method it doesn't even allow me to add it as the 'Application' run configuration in Intellij. I don't actually want to have that as a run configuration, I just want to be able to set breakpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ has a module to test scalaTest classes. Just right-click on the name of your class, and click on `Debug in ScalaTest` (the first time around, you should have a dropdown on `Debug` to select how you want to run it).

Comment: edit - wtfbbq it just popped up ... hate this tool sometimes